# Write Net::IMAP email to mikel/mail email

Tags: ruby

I have problem with passing email fetched with `Net::IMAP` library to `Mail` object defined with `mikel/mail` gem.

I get mail with:

```
data = imap.uid_fetch(1, "BODY[]")
```

but how should I later put it into Mail.read convention?

```
mail = Mail.read(data.to_s)
```

seems to get `Errno::ENAMETOOLONG: File name too long`. It understands mail body as filename.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Mail.read` wants a filename. Use `Mail.new` to initialize a `Mail` object from an email source.

Also, fetch `RFC822`, not `BODY[]`.

```
mail = Mail.new(imap.uid_fetch(1, "RFC822")[0].attr["RFC822"])
```